# Should I start looking for job elsewhere?

Tags: software-industry

I have been working in a software company for the past year. My rapport with the boss is not good lately, as there where some bugs in code which was released during my absence. Since I have come back from leave (which has been about 1 week) he has not talked to me. So I don't know what to expect from him. Chances of him firing me are low, but I feel that I am not that valued in the company.

Now I am in dilemma over whether to start looking elsewhere for the job or wait for 1 more year before switching.

Pros for switching company are:

1. I will get better paid.
2. I can prove myself. (In current company I am not able to be myself)

Cons:

1. I have to start all over again
2. In the project I am working on I get to learn a lot, so I would miss out on that.

Just need your to help me out cause I don't want to take any rash or emotional decisions.

Comment: Is your boss not talking to you for a week very unusual?

Comment: He does not talk much, but the project manager said he was furious when there where bugs.

Comment: mandatory xkcd : https://xkcd.com/1768/

Comment: Unless you go somewhere that doesn't release any software, you will probably release bugs from time to time, too. Is there no possibility to fix the bugs in the next release?

Comment: Is it your responsibility alone to perform quality assurance?  If the bugs in question are in code that you wrote, it should be somebody else who tests it.  If nobody tested it, that's not your fault.  If I were your boss I'd be furious too - at myself.

Answer (score 2):

The only person who can make this decision is you. That said, if you really don't like your job, moving on is always an option.

One thing to remember, you are not "switching companies", you are applying for a new job. That means that you will be selling yourself to a nw company, you will need a solid CV/resume, a good reference, sufficient knowledge and a not-petty reason for leaving (always speak in positives like "more opportunities for growth", "more challenging work", etc)